# Just want to show a Popup Or Status bar during running of VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a long code & taking approx. 1 min 30 sec to execute , So I want to show a Status bar showing "Please wait...running" or a popup with the same message or anything else which on will be easy.
It consist so many do while, for & if conditions..
I don't want to use any Long code Or very heavy method to show the message, Please suggest some small way to do this.

Comment: see [Application.StatusBar property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835916.aspx)

Comment: Do I have to make any changes...
I just Put the 
`oldStatusBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar `
`Application.DisplayStatusBar = True` 
`Application.StatusBar = "Please be patient..." `
before the code & Put these line
`Application.StatusBar = False` 
`Application.DisplayStatusBar = oldStatusBar`
before the End Sub but it not works.

Comment: edit your question to update the title, add the code you tried, and tell us what problem you have i.e. how do you notice *"it not works"*

Comment: I just written that I put my whole code just b/w those lines.... & after run there is no changes is happening . I didn't get any popup or Status bar & runs as it was running before

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short procedure that will demonstrate adjusting the [Application.StatusBar property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835916.aspx) text in a loop.

```
Sub sb_text()
    Dim w As Long, s As Long, d As Double

    s = 2 '<~~ seconds between actions

    Application.StatusBar = "Preparing ..."
    d = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, s): Do While Now < d: DoEvents: Loop

    For w = 1 To 5
        Application.StatusBar = "Working: " & w
        d = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, s): Do While Now < d: DoEvents: Loop
    Next w

    Application.StatusBar = "Finished"
    d = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, s): Do While Now < d: DoEvents: Loop

    Application.StatusBar = vbNullString
End Sub
```

I've set a two second pause so that you can actually observe the changes to the status bar text. In an actual procedure loop, the waiting would be replaced by actual work being done.

Comment: An `Application.StatusBar = False` will put the familiar 'Ready' into the status bar instead of just a blank line.

Comment: Are you trying to tell me that `Application.StatusBar = vbNullString` does NOT reset the status bar text to `Ready` on your system?

Comment: @Jeeped: where I have to put my whole code in your given code?

Comment: @ksrds - Use the [F8] key in the VBE to step through the procedure I wrote and you should be able to determine where you want to put your code.

Comment: I am not getting any changes....it's just going through all the code & didn't make any changes. I am not getting where I have to put my code.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. If that procedure is not producing results on your status bar text then our systems are incompatible.